# Get complex data from Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a complex JSON using nested class.

```
employees{
   employeeCode
   name:"LION",
   address:"",
   jobs{
      jobCode:1
      jobName:"developer",
      jobDescription:""
   },
   salary{
      salaryCode:xxx
      fisrtMonth:xxx
      fromSecondMonth:xxx
   }
```

Data get from 3 tables(employee, job, salary) with multiple field(100 fields/table).

Now to set data for JSON, i have two options:

1. Using JPA get 3 entities, after that using model mapper to map these entity to dto class.

```
Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeCode);
Job job = jobRepository.findById(jobCode);
Salary salary = salaryRepository.findById(salaryCode);

EmployeeDTO dto = new EmployeeDTO();
this.modelmapper.map(employee, dto);
this.modelmapper.map(job, dto);
this.modelmapper.map(salary, dto);
```

2. Create native query to get data from 3 tables, after that setting value for dto class.

```
MemberRepository.java
@query="SELECT"
        + "e.employeeCode,"
        + "e.name,"
        + "e.address,"
        + "j.jobCode,"
        + "j.jobName,"
        + "j.jobDescription,"
        + "s.salaryCode,"
        + "s.fisrtMonth,"
        + "s.fromSecondMonth"
        + "FROM Employee e"
        + "INNER JOIN Job j on e.jobCode = j.jobCode"
        + "INNER JOIN salary on e.salaryCode = s.salaryCode"
        + "WHERE e.employeeCode=?1"
        ,nativeQuery=true)
List<Object[]> getEmployeeInfo(int employeeCode);
```

```
EmployeeService.java
List<Object[]> employeeInfoList = this.employeeRepository.getEmployeeInfo(employeeCd);
//loop employeeInfoList and set data to DTO
```

what should i do? which is best choice?

Comment: you can use projections also

Comment: Since you are a beginner here if you don't want to earn minuses please paste some of your code here. Don't expect developers to assume what you want to do by just reading your question.

Comment: @MiroslavTrninic i updated my question. thanks

Comment: @Eklavya DTO will get data from 3 tables, projections can work with?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best strategy in this case is to map the entities using @JoinColumns and relationship annotations. With a relational entity mapping you would not need any queries, just query by ID using standard methods of JPA implementations and worry only with the mapper for the DTO.

E se estiver utilizando Springboot fica ainda mais simples.

Comment: Now, entities does not have any @JoinColumns. I have to use mapper to map entities. Do you have any idea for this?